# How do I make a post request of a json nested in flutter?

Tags: json

I will make the normal request in a simple JSON, but when it is written I will not make the request. If anyone can help me with the post request of this JSON and model.

**JSON:**

```
{
    "nit":12335667,
    "name": "it",
    "city": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "New York",
        "code": 132
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If what you are looking for is to make a post, something like that would still work, but I would recommend this [article](https://medium.com/swlh/how-to-make-http-requests-in-flutter-d12e98ee1cef).

```
class MyPostRequest extends StatelessWidget {

  final location = {
    "nit": 12335667,
    "name": "it",
    "city": {"id": 1, "name": "New York", "code": 132}
  };

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FlatButton(
      child: Text('Make a Post Request'),
      onPressed: () async {
        var response = await http.post(
          'https://www.example.com',
          body: location,
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```